# How to change input dimensions for LSTM layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I need to make a model that has 2 dropout layers and two LSTM layers. Unfortunately I have a problem with input shape that goes to my second LSTM layer. After searching for the problem I found out I need to change the input dimensions but I don't know how to do that. I found an option that requires using Lambda layer but I can't import it to my environmet (it's a coursera environment). Have you got any suggestions how to deal with my error?

```
model = Sequential()
Layer1 = model.add(Embedding(total_words, 64, input_length=max_sequence_len-1))
Layer2 = model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20)))
Layer3 = model.add(Dropout(.03))
Layer4 = model.add(LSTM(20))
Layer5 = model.add(Dense(total_words, 
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
    bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)))
          # A Dense Layer including regularizers
Layer6 = model.add(Dense(total_words, activation = 'softmax'))
          
# Pick an optimizer
          
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_20 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 40]
```

Comment: use return_sequences=True in the LSTM in Layer2

Comment: @MarcoCerliani as far as I understand - the input to the first LSTM is wrong

Comment: No, the error doesn't say this, it's more simple... it's because she didn't set return_sequences

Comment: @MarcoCerliani you were right! Thank you so much. It helped me. For some reason I thought I only need to use `return_sequences=True` when two LSTMs are directly stacked one on the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @Marco Cerliani and @Joanna Kastelik for the update.

For the benefit of community providing solution here using sample data as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Bidirectional, LSTM, Dropout,  Dense
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1_l2, l2

total_words = 478
max_sequence_len = 90

model = Sequential()
Layer1 = model.add(Embedding(total_words, 64, input_length=max_sequence_len-1))
Layer2 = model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20)))
Layer3 = model.add(Dropout(.03))
Layer4 = model.add(LSTM(20))
Layer5 = model.add(Dense(total_words, 
    kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
    bias_regularizer=l2(1e-4),
    activity_regularizer=l2(1e-5)))
          # A Dense Layer including regularizers
Layer6 = model.add(Dense(total_words, activation = 'softmax'))
          
# Pick an optimizer
          
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8ce04225c92d> in <module>()
     12 Layer2 = model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20)))
     13 Layer3 = model.add(Dropout(.03))
---> 14 Layer4 = model.add(LSTM(20))
     15 Layer5 = model.add(Dense(total_words, 
     16     kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    221                          'expected ndim=' + str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
    222                          str(ndim) + '. Full shape received: ' +
--> 223                          str(tuple(shape)))
    224     if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    225       ndim = x.shape.rank

ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 40)
```

**Fixed code:**

Your issue can be resolved once you add `return_sequences=True` to the LSTM (i.e, Layer2) layer.

```
model = Sequential()
Layer1 = model.add(Embedding(total_words, 64, input_length=max_sequence_len-1))
Layer2 = model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True)))
Layer3 = model.add(Dropout(.03))
Layer4 = model.add(LSTM(20))
Layer5 = model.add(Dense(total_words, 
    kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
    bias_regularizer=l2(1e-4),
    activity_regularizer=l2(1e-5)))
          # A Dense Layer including regularizers
Layer6 = model.add(Dense(total_words, activation = 'softmax'))
          
# Pick an optimizer
          
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 89, 64)            30592     
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 89, 40)            13600     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 89, 40)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 20)                4880      
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 478)               10038     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 478)               228962    
=================================================================
Total params: 288,072
Trainable params: 288,072
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error also after using the `return_sequences=True` in the LSTM layer issue does not solve. Here is my piece of code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, activation='tanh', name='layer1', input_shape=(N_input,), kernel_initializer=K_initializer,bias_initializer=B_initializer, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='tanh', name='layer2', kernel_initializer=K_initializer, bias_initializer=B_initializer, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', name='layer3', kernel_initializer=K_initializer, bias_initializer=B_initializer))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu', name='layer4', kernel_initializer=K_initializer, bias_initializer=B_initializer))

print(model.summary())
```

Comment: please post the error you are getting

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34487451)